# Поиск в нескольких таблицах с разделением результата

Tags: mysql

Допустим, есть несколько таблиц, у которых есть похожие поля (не обязательно одноимённые: title, name...). Необходимо сделать выборку вида LIKE %??%, так чтобы в итоге понимать, в какой конкретно таблице найдено значение.

То есть вот такой запрос выводит все найденные строки, но не идентифицирует таблицу:

```
SELECT title, id AS id_1 FROM tbl_1 WHERE title LIKE %$txt%
UNION     
SELECT title, id AS id_2 FROM tbl_2 WHERE title LIKE %$txt%
```

То есть даже если в первой таблице будет пусто, а во второй найдено, будет выведен результат, присвоенный **`tbl_1`**:

```
[title] => xxx
[id_2] => 123
```

Для наглядности: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/126255/2/0

А результат хотелось бы видеть примерно так:

```
[title] => xxx
[id_1] => null
[id_2] => 123

[title] => xxxzzz
[id_1] => null
[id_2] => 456

[title] => wwwxxx
[id_1] => 1212
[id_2] => null

...
```

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/311718/

Comment: В этом примере таблицы связаны по idCountry / CountryId, а в моём примере таблицы никак не связаны.

Comment: Там главное волшебное слово pivot, а ваши таблицы связаны по title или ещё как-то, я не совсем понимаю, но если связи нет, то и решения нет.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, да. Связи нет, но решение придумал. Может, и не идеальное, но работающее:

```
SELECT title,id,('t_1') AS tbl_name FROM tbl_1 WHERE title LIKE '%$query%'
UNION
SELECT title,id,('t_2') FROM tbl_2 WHERE title LIKE '%$query%'
```

Теперь в поле tbl_name можно видеть имя таблицы, в которой найдено совпадение.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/126255/24/0